# KVO observeValueForKeyPath method called twice

Tags: ios

I write a demo wanted to trying KVO programming,I found the observeValueForKeyPath
method always execute twice when i only change value once,what's wrong?please help me,Thanks

code

StatusSyncer.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

 @interface StatusSyncer : NSObject
 @property NSString *title;
 +(instancetype)sharedInstance;
@end
```

StatusSyncer.m

```
#import "StatusSyncer.h"
@implementation StatusSyncer
+ (instancetype)sharedInstance {
   static id _sharedInstance = nil;
   static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;
   dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
      _sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
   });
   return _sharedInstance;
}
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   [self.statusSyncer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"title"    options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];

 }

 -(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context{
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
        NSLog(@"chane");
    }
}

-(StatusSyncer *)statusSyncer{
    if (_statusSyncer==nil) {
        _statusSyncer = [StatusSyncer sharedInstance];
    }

    return _statusSyncer;
}
```

DetailViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)changeAction:(id)sender {
    self.statusSyncer.title= @"newTitle叶";

}

-(StatusSyncer *)statusSyncer{
    if (_statusSyncer==nil) {
        _statusSyncer = [StatusSyncer sharedInstance];
    }

    return _statusSyncer;
}
```

output：

```
2015-06-15 12:58:49.849 KVOAdvence[2433:74541] chane
2015-06-15 12:58:49.850 KVOAdvence[2433:74541] chane
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the method **addObserver:** is performed twice.

You will check other controllers inheritance, it may extends **ViewController**

Answer (score 1):

OOOh,I  Make a stupid mistake 
DetailViewController super class is ViewController,This make StatusSyncer add
twice Observer